# Как настроить mod rewrite и htaccess для переадресации на *.html?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

В корне директории сайта есть html файлы на двух языках. Имеют вид:

```
company.html
services.html
index.html
en_company.html
en_services.html
en_index.html
```

Задача настроить переадресацию:

```
www.site.com/ > www.site.com/index.html
www.site.com/company/ > www.site.com/company.html

www.site.com/en/ > www.site.com/index.html
www.site.com/en/company/ > www.site.com/en_company.html
```

Что не так?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ $1.php [L,NC,NE,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/en/]*)/$ en_$1.php [L,NC,NE,QSA]
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У Вас несоответствие типов файлов. Вы указали, что у Вас в директории файлы с расширением `.html`, а в правиле используете расширение `.php`